# The access to shared directory using DFS is very slow

Tags: active-directory, virtual-machines, windows-server-2019, dfs

I have an Active Directory with 1 DC and  1 DFS deployed on hyper-v VM on a certain machine X. The DFS consists of several shared folders from machine X and folders from machine Z. When I try to access the DFS using network drive all works fine for machine Z folders. But I have some problems with folders from machine X. The access to machine X folders is very slow. Sometimes it takes several minutes to open even small file. When I try to upload files to machine X folders all works fine but the download speed is very small. The upload speed is about tens of Mb/s but download speed ~ 100 kb.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: DFS is essentially a redirect to whatever the best server is. So, In both cases, the computer connects directly to server Z. For that reason, DFS would not affect transfer speed. So you may be misinterpreting your data, or the problem is not transfer speed related at all. Instead it is most likely a DNS issue or a DFS configuration problem.

Comment: I have 1 DNS server on the same VM with DC. All my machines have static IPs and nslookup works fine for machines X, Z and for VM. Tracert returns correct results too. I'm very confused, what kind of settings of DFS may provide such problems. there are not so many.

Comment: one dns could be not enough to handle all the time all request. did you think about a secondary one?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are some problems with hyper-v VMs and their communication with NIC. I have disabled the "Large Send Offload" feature in network adapter settings and everything starts working fine. So it is very strange, I supposed this feature should be useful.